# Pagina web me indica que no tengo la extension mysqli a pesar de que si la tengo activada. (Windows)

Tags: php, mysql, windows10

tengo un problema que me ha tenido calentando el craneo hace ya un mes.

Estoy un haciendo un servicio web CRUD para un proyecto universitario, asi que decidi empezar por programar cada funcion por separado.

Aun no logro que mi codigo html logre llamar a la funcion PHP, pero eso es para otro dia. Mi problema actual es que entro a la funcion php desde ella misma (estoy usando un servidor Apache, tengo la funcion php en la carpeta de php y puedo entrar con localhost).

El codigo en si funciona, asumiendo que no intento conectarme la base de datos, pero cuando intento hacerlo con la funcion

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost ,$dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

(Estoy seguro que los datos que tengo son los correctos).

Me aparece este problema en la pagina web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigue y significa que no tengo la extension de mysqli, pero el punto es que investigue el archivo php.ini y resulta que si la tengo activada (me refiero a que no esta comentada)

¿Alguien sabe alguna otra solucion?

Deberia decir que estoy usando windows 10, y que instale php y Xampp de manera aparte.

Comment: si usas xampp para que installas php???

Comment: me entere de la existencia de Xampp dias despues de que instale php (y aun asi no sabia muy bien como servia o que hacia)

Comment: bueno solo desintala php y corre el de xampp o cambia los archivos a la carpeta de `C:\xampp\htcdocs\tuproyecto\``  y corre php desde xampp y ya solo debes acceder a `localhost/tuproyecto/`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!!